# CDI Interceptor not simultaneous to current request in servlet

Tags: servlets, jakarta-ee, cdi

Sorry for the title, i have no idea to get better title.

I create a simple servlet and implements CDI interceptor.

This is my servlet

```
@Inject
UserManagement user;

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    user.setUsername(request.getParameter("username"));
    response.getWriter().println(user.getMessage());
}
```

This is UserManagement bean:

```
@SessionScoped
public class UserManagement implements Serializable{

    private String username;
    private String message = "";

    @UsernameSet
    public void setUsername(String username){
        this.username = username;
    }
}
```

This is interceptor binding (@UsernameSet):

```
@InterceptorBinding
@Inherited
@Target({ TYPE, METHOD })
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Documented
public @interface UsernameSet {
}
```

This is the interceptor:

```
@UsernameSet
@Interceptor
public class UserInterceptor implements Serializable {

    @Inject
    UserManagement user;

    @AroundInvoke
    public Object aroundInvoke(InvocationContext ic) throws Exception {
        LOGGER.info("Entering method: " + ic.getMethod().getName());
        user.setMessage("Hello " + user.getUsername());
        return ic.proceed();
    }
}
```

The interceptor does work but the servlet return `UserManagement` bean from previous request, although the logger shows immediately.

**example**

First Request:
`localhost?username=smitty`

Browser screen:
`Hello`

Second Request:
`localhost?username=werben`

Browser screen:
`Hello smitty`

Third Request:
`localhost?username=jensen`

Browser screen:
`Hello werben`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create an interceptor, it's invoked either before or after your method is called.  With the way you have written yours, it is invoked before your method is called.  `InvocationContext.proceed` will effectively call your method (and other interceptors if others are wired in).

To get the behavior you're looking for, you can switch to this:

```
@UsernameSet
@Interceptor
public class UserInterceptor implements Serializable {

    @Inject
    UserManagement user;

    @AroundInvoke
    public Object aroundInvoke(InvocationContext ic) throws Exception {
        LOGGER.info("Entering method: " + ic.getMethod().getName());
        Object result = ic.proceed();
        user.setMessage("Hello " + user.getUsername());
        return result;
    }
}
```